# How to space row headings and position captions of subtables

Tags: tables, matrices, tabularx

I have been trying to construct a 3x3 confusion matrix using pdfLatex. My output so far is included in the image below along with my code for it.

I am having trouble with two aspects of the matrices.

Firstly I need to increase the space between "Actual Value" and the "Left", "Right" and "Straight" row headings along the sides of the matrices, however so far I have been unable to get it right.

Secondly, I need to shift the sub-caption "(b) Part 2", at the bottom of the second matrix, to the left so that it aligns with the middle row of the matrix like sub-caption "(a) Part 1" does for the first matrix.

How could I go about making the above two fixes?

I've tried to neaten the code as much as possible. I am pretty new and so I may not be using the best methods possible. Any further advice with regards to improvements will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{center}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \caption{Confusion Matrix}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{subtable}{0.49\linewidth}
        \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries Prediction outcome} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Left}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Straight}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Right}}\\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{13}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{1.1cm}{\bfseries \mbox{Actual Value}}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{1.1cm}{\textbf{Left}}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\MyBox{0}{ }} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\MyBox{1}{ }} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\MyBox{2}{ }}\\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{1}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{1cm}{\textbf{Straight}}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\MyBox{0}{ }} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\MyBox{1}{ }} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\MyBox{2}{ }}\\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{1.1cm}{\textbf{Right}}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\MyBox{0}{ }} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\MyBox{1}{ }} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\MyBox{2}{ }}
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Part 1}
    \end{subtable}
    \begin{subtable}{0.49\linewidth}
         \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
             \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries Prediction outcome} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
             \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Left}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Straight}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Right}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\
             \multicolumn{1}{c}{\MyBox{1000}{ }} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\MyBox{1}{ }} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\MyBox{2}{ }} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox{270}{\parbox{1cm}{\textbf{Left}}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{9}{*}{\rotatebox{270}{\parbox{1.2cm}{\bfseries \mbox{Actual Value}}}}}\\
             \multicolumn{1}{c}{\MyBox{0}{ }} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\MyBox{1}{ }} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\MyBox{2}{ }} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\rotatebox{270}{\parbox{-10cm}{\textbf{Straight}}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\MyBox{0}{ }} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\MyBox{1}{ }} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\MyBox{2}{ }} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{1}{*}{\rotatebox{270}{\parbox{1.1cm}{\textbf{Right}}}}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
         \end{tabular}
         \caption{Part 2}
     \end{subtable}
     \end{center}
\end{table}
```

[image: My confusion matrix]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Filling the code so it becomes a compilable document would be better.

Comment: While all the `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}`?

Comment: I'll upload a compilable document next time. Thanks for the advice

Comment: I used \multicolumn{1}{c}{} as I found out that this is one of the best ways to make a column without the lines showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simpler code for one of the subtables. Hopefully, it should correspond to what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating, multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\MyBox}[1]{{\parbox[c][1.4cm][c]{1.1cm}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\rotbox}[1]{ \rotatebox[origin = c]{90}{\makebox[0pt]{\bfseries#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{Confusion Matrix}
\label{tab:table1}
\begin{subtable}{0.49\linewidth}
    \begin{tabular}{c@{\enspace }c|c|c|c|}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries Prediction outcome} \\
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Left}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makebox[0pt]{\textbf{Straight}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Right}}\\[0.5ex]
\cline{3-5}
    & \rotbox{Left} & \MyBox{0} & \MyBox{1} & \MyBox{2} \\
\cline{3-5}
 \rotbox{Actual value} & \rotbox{Straight} & \MyBox{0} & \MyBox{1} & \MyBox{2} \\
\cline{3-5}
    & \rotbox{Right} & \MyBox{0} & \MyBox{1} & \MyBox{2} \\
\cline{3-5}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Part 1}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. This was perfect! I'll remember to come up-vote when I get enough reputation points